# Scrape data from table

Tags: python, selenium

First, I have tried with bs4, but the table is not plain html text and thats why I moved to selenium

I'm trying to scrape the table data, but I dont know how to get the information.

What I have now is:

```
table =  browser.find_element_by_id("name_list")  
cell = table.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@style='text-align:center']")
```

The table data is displayed like this:

```
<td style="text-align:center" class="left"><script   
type="text/javascript">document.write(Base64.decode("MTA0LjI0OC4xMTUuMjM2"))</script>"John"</td>
```

I want to get "John" but how can I get it?

Comment: it is normal <td> in table. Where is the problem? Or maybe you need text from `Base64.decode("MTA0LjI0OC4xMTUuMjM2")` There is no problem too, you can find `<script>` and you have string which you can slice to get `MTA0LjI0OC4xMTUuMjM2` and use with Python module `base64`

Comment: Oh, I didn't knew about this. Thank you very much, I will give a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with BeautifulSoup

If you have `<script>` in `<td>` then you can use iterator `.children` and get second/last element (first will be `<script>`)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = '''<td style="text-align:center" class="left"><script   
type="text/javascript">document.write(Base64.decode("MTA0LjI0OC4xMTUuMjM2"))</script>"John"</td>'''

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
td = soup.find('td')

text = list(td.children)[1]

print(text) # John
```

or you can find `<script>` and `extract` it so you will have `<td>` only with text

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html = '''<td style="text-align:center" class="left"><script   
type="text/javascript">document.write(Base64.decode("MTA0LjI0OC4xMTUuMjM2"))</script>"John"</td>'''

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
td = soup.find('td')

td.find('script').extract()
text = td.text

print(td.text) # John
```

if you need text from `Base64.decode("MTA0LjI0OC4xMTUuMjM2")` then you can find `<script>` and get it as text. Using slicing you can get text `MTA0LjI0OC4xMTUuMjM2` and decode with module `base64`. And you get text `104.248.115.236`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import base64

html = '''<td style="text-align:center" class="left"><script   
type="text/javascript">document.write(Base64.decode("MTA0LjI0OC4xMTUuMjM2"))</script>"John"</td>'''

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')
td = soup.find('td')

script = td.find('script').text

text = script[30:-3]

text = base64.b64decode(text).decode()

print(text) # 104.248.115.236
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text using the below line.

```
table.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@style='text-align:center']").text
```

Make sure the <kbd>.</kbd> is there in the xpath to restrict the scope to the current table node.